# What happen to "Add Watch" and "Evaluate in Console" - google chrome canary

Tags: google-chrome

Pretty weird I must say. I am using google Chrome Canary for dev purposes and use to right click to Evaluate in console or to 'Add Watch'. However, one day both commands disappeared from the context menu. I have a few copies of canary running on independent virtual machines and they are all act the same.

Did google change anything??

thanks,
David

Comment: I'm getting the same thing now in Chrome 39.  Are they trying to make their devtools crappier?